# Why is java.io.FileDescriptor's constructor public?

Tags: java

JavaDoc for [java.io.FileDescriptor.FileDescriptor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#FileDescriptor%28%29) says:

> Constructs an (invalid) FileDescriptor object.

If there is no purpose for the constructor, why is it's access level not declared to be *package-private*?

Comment: You're asking the wrong people in the wrong place. You will get a lot of opinion and guesswork, at least until the question is closed as not constructive,  but the only people who actually know are unlikely to be found here.

Comment: @s106mo I don't agree that it's a mistake, and I don't agree with the OP that there is no purpose to it: that's just begging the question. They may have been planning for e.g. Java.net.Socket to use it. We don't know.

Comment: @s106mo *by mistake* should not be a satisfying answer because it is not correct. There is a reason, see my answer.

Comment: @EJP I'm not looking for opinions or guesswork. "The people who know are unlikely to be found here" does not mean that the question itself does not suit the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Those people are still alive, and thus this is an answerable question. http://serverfault.com/a/259642/87017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This constructor is public because it is used outside of `java.io`.

Classes using `new FileDescriptor()` in JRE 7u4 Linux x86:

```
java.io.FileInputStream
java.io.FileOutputStream
java.io.RandomAccessFile

java.lang.UNIXProcess
java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
java.net.ServerSocket

sun.net.sdp.SdpSupport
sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl
sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl
sun.nio.ch.IOUtil
sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl
sun.nio.ch.SctpServerChannelImpl
sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl
sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl
sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory
```

There is a `sun.misc.SharedSecrets` method that allows the programmer to change the state of a `FileDescriptor` to a valid one (this snippet found in `java.io.FileDescriptor`):

```
  static {
        sun.misc.SharedSecrets.setJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess(
            new sun.misc.JavaIOFileDescriptorAccess() {
                public void set(FileDescriptor obj, int fd) {
                    obj.fd = fd;
                }

                public int get(FileDescriptor obj) {
                    return obj.fd;
                }

                public void setHandle(FileDescriptor obj, long handle) {
                    obj.handle = handle;
                }

                public long getHandle(FileDescriptor obj) {
                    return obj.handle;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

This means that any code that can access `SharedSecrets` (I.E. the JRE itself) can also create its own valid `FileDescriptor`, and should therefore be allowed to access `FileDescriptor()`. However, there is no way to restrict the access of a constructor to only JRE classes, so it is public.

Answer (score -2):

Your answer can be found on the class level documentation:

@since JDK1.0

This is also the answer for questions such as "Why is Number an abstract class rather than an interface", "Why is Vector synchronized?", etc.

Classes that are that old may or may not have @Deprecated warnings on them, but Java has been really soft in its removal of deprecated features.  Cruft like this keeps appearing because the classes are useful yet the internal Java upgrading process tends to not remove deprecated methods but keep them around because that keeps backwards compatibility all the way since the initial Java release.

Comment: This tells us why the constructor is still public, but not why it was public in the first place.

Comment: It also conflates deprecation with unexpected access control. There is no way to apply deprecation to this issue. @since 1.0 is not an answer to this question.